# Why doesn't Sphinx have BM25 with field weights?

Tags: sphinx

The formula for Sphinx default ranker, `SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25` looks like this:

```
SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 = sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25
```

The Longest Common Subsequence is computed for each field separately and then multiplied by `user_weight`. However `bm25` is just a document-wide variable and does not take user fields into account. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it's faster and in many cases the quality is enough. There's a custom ranker and bm25f to be used there. Document length is also not accounted by default, it requires index_field_lengths=1 during indexing.